# PHP const from an expression

Tags: php, yii2

I have a class (`MetricUnits`) that looks like this:

```
class MetricUnit {
    const SIZE = [
        "value" => 0,
        "text" => Yii::t("app", "Size")
    ];
}
```

`Yii::t` is a i18n function.
As you'd be probably thinking by now, this is invalid as PHP doesn't allow expressions in const.

How can I avoid that limitation so I could get the text of that cons?

Btw, `Yii::t` doesn't take any non-string values, not even const values, so I can't do something like:

```
class MetricUnit {
    const SIZE = [
        "value" => 0,
        "text" => "Size"
    ];
}

Yii::t("app", MetricUnit::SIZE["text"]);
```

Comment: not possible. you cannot "run code" outside of a method in an object, therefore you can't call the `Yii` function to set the `text` value. And you can't have something like `const $this::foo` inside the constructor to define it at runtime - const is only valid OUTSIDE of methods. use a regular variable and live with it...

Comment: @alexandernst I think you can't avoid this limitation, and you probably will have to create two const

Comment: @gildonei How are to const going to help?

Comment: @alexandernst - You are alright, it won't. You can't use they. sry.

Comment: That second solution should work since `MetricUnit::SIZE['text']`  would return a string - but then again, I guess the real deal is that you cannot specify const's like that

Comment: @rm-vanda The problem here is that `Yii::t` is, from what I understand, a "marker" and not an actual function. Meaning that messages aren't translated at runtime, but with a command that you run manually. So... `Yii::t` just can't see anything that isn't a plain string.

Comment: Looking at the source code, that is false. `Yii::t()` can, in fact, accept the method, as above. The problem is you cannot define a const as an array.

Comment: @rm-vanda Please look at the issue I opened. One of Yii2 devs says it can't: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/8874

Comment: I will definitely look into this, tonight - since this is quite an interesting puzzle, but from the looks of it, there is a serious misunderstanding by the Yii devs, there - there's not really any way for it to "not execute code" like you describe.

Comment: Proof of concept: https://gist.github.com/rmvanda/ade4cc483fb3d6bb4e35

Comment: @rm-vanda Could you post your findings in the issue I opened so Yii devs can read it too, please?

Comment: Why is something that's called a "unit" actually an amount together with the translated version of a property that would be expressed as an amount of units?

Comment: @JasperN.Brouwer Please ignore the actual naming of the clase. That is a simple example.

Comment: Make that the cat wise :D

Answer (score 1):

As it was mentioned, you cannot run calculations like that -

Furthermore, since you have to do some calculation to get that attribute, then technically, it isn't really a *constant value* constant -

So, I would recommend you do this:

```
class MetricUnit {

     public static $SIZE;

     public static getSize(){
          return self::$SIZE ? : self::$SIZE = array(
             "value" => 0,
             "text" => Yii::t("app", "Size")
         );
     }

}
```